# Prevent S3 user from posting to public buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Suppose a public bucket exists that has a very similar name to my private bucket. I want to prevent a user from misspelling the private bucket and accidentally posting sensitive data to the public.

I understand that it would be best practice to make the bucket name as unique as possible.

Clarification: I want to prevent a user from posting to ANY public S3 bucket

Comment: Not really, I want to prevent the user from posting to ANY public bucket.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html Check this

Answer (score 1):

*Public Buckets* are very rare. In fact, they are highly discouraged from a **security** perspective and also from a **cost** perspective -- somebody could upload illegal files and use it for file sharing, and the bucket owner would pay for it!

I would normally say that the chance of somebody being able to successfully upload to a random bucket is practically zero, but I suspect you are thinking of a case where an **evil party** might create a similarly-named bucket in the hope of collecting confidential data (similar to domain-name camping).

In that case, you can create a Deny policy on the user to **prohibit access to ALL S3 buckets, except for the ones you specifically nominate**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::good-bucket1",
                "arn:aws:s3:::good-bucket2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "NotOthers",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "NotResource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::good-bucket1",
                "arn:aws:s3:::good-bucket2"                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This will work because the `Deny` against the IAM User will override any `Allow` in a Bucket Policy. The only downside is that **you will need to specifically list the buckets you wish to include/exclude** because there is no way to specify that rules apply to "a public bucket".

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over the other bucket, so you can't prevent this happening.

To respond to it, I suppose you could query that bucket periodically, assuming it's publicly readable, in search of content that you think should have been uploaded to *your* bucket though it's not clear what you would do at that point.

Alternatively, provide your users with an upload page (maybe statically-hosted in your S3 bucket) and ask your users to use that page to initiate uploads (via [POST](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) or AWS S3 JavaScript SDK) so users do not have to type in a bucket name and hence cannot accidentally target the wrong bucket.